# Can range index creation be scheduled in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

MarkLogic Version - 9

Consider -  I have 3 collections with huge documents in it.

collection1: Order
    document count - 10M
    element - orderNumber

collection2: Inventory
    document count - 100M

collection3: Payment
    document count - 50M

Ex: We want to create a range index for element "orderNumber" for all the documents in collection1(Order). This is not a one-time thing and our code requires dynamic range index creation on different elements in the documents based on user operation in UI.

Since this range index creation is triggered by user operation in UI we do not want the DB to massively slow down trying to index all the available documents in DB.

**So can we schedule the reindexing in MarkLogic as per the downtime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not merging for extended time when you are doing a lot of updates can create a situation where the number of stands exceeds hard limits and your forest is unusable. I would also say it is always going to be more expensive to run a reindex than to have the correct index settings at ingestion time: you will pay for extra updates, extra merges, etc. Reindexing will only process as many documents as are relevant to a particular index setting: if that is all documents it will take at least as long as the initial load would have.

I would also say that if your code expects to change index settings on a regular basis, you are doing something wrong. Indexing configuration is expected to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing itself is fairly fast, and usually not the cause of 'massive slow downs'. You can lower the throttle though, if you prefer. You can find it under the Configure tab of the database in the Admin UI.

Reindexing will cause deleted fragments however, which in turn will trigger merging. Merging is usually the process that slows down the most. You can also throttle merging, and even set [`Blackout Periods for Merges`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/merges#id_12834).

**Important: use blackouts with care. Not merging for an extended time will decrease overall MarkLogic performance.**

HTH!